# Enabling vertex rotation in MxGraph

Tags: javascript, rotation, draw, mxgraph

I want to enable vertex (object) rotation in mxGraph, can anyone tell me how to do it? I don't want to do it by setting the 'rotation=45 , rotation=-90' etc. I want the user to be able to rotate the object on the designer.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, just add this line in your javascript file.

```
mxVertexHandler.prototype.rotationEnabled = true;
```